# Voximplant – the callSIP method to call a phone number

Tags: voximplant

I want to use the Voximplant's callSIP method to call a phone number. Is it possible? How do I specify a number to call in the VoxEngine.callSIP() method?

Answer (score 0):

When you call via callSIP, you make a call to a 3rd-party PBX. If the PBX allows calling to phone numbers, yes, you can do it, but you need to find out what format the PBX accepts.

In most cases, you can specify the number in the To field in the username part of the SIP address, for example: number_to_call@domain. Alternatively, you can call a phone number directly through Voximplant via the callPSTN() method.